# I'm trying to make it so when a bannedID runs a command it replies with a ephemeral message that says "You are banned from usage" but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When a "bannedId" tries to run the command it's supposed to make the response only visible to them and say "You are banned from usage" but instead when anyone tries to run the command it just says "The application did not respond". Any ideas?

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
if (!interaction.isCommand()) {
    return
}

const { commandName, options } = interaction

if (commandName === 'ping') {
    if ((message.author.id) === bannedid)
         return interaction.reply({
            content: 'You are banned from usage',
            ephemeral: true,
         })
    interaction.reply({
        content: 'pong',
        //ephemeral: true,
    })
}
```

})

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bannedId` is an array, you can use the [Array.Prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if the `bannedId` array includes the message author’s id:
`bannedId.includes(message.author.id)`

Comment: Also, I’d like to apologize if I made any mistake in my answer as I’m currently on my phone and it’s 1:30 am

Comment: I tried it but it made the " interaction.reply({
        content: 'pong',
        //ephemeral: true,
    })
}" part unreachable

Comment: Huh? Can you send a sourcebin link of your current code? Sorry for the 9 hours late reply, I was sleeping.